# How to grant permissions to SYS objects in Oracle AWS RDS?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS Oracle database. I would like to grant access to some sys objects with grant option.

I run :

```
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('DBA_OBJECTS', 'MASTER_USER', 'SELECT', true);
```

But I'm getting the error :

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 164:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GRANT_SYS_OBJECT'
```

I doesn't like the last parameter 'true'. As per the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.System.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.TransferPrivileges) this parameter is for grant option.

If I run the command without the grant option :

```
exec rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('DBA_OBJECTS', 'MASTER_USER', 'SELECT');
```

It works but it grants the privilege without the grant option.

Does anyone know how to grant a privilege with grant option in AWS Oracle RDS please ?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Oracle specifically? You may need to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is coming from an old release, or because you are not informing which parameters correspond with this order.

I would suggest to run it as documented. Why ? Because when you don't inform the parameters, Oracle will run it sequentially using the order in which they were defined when such package/procedure/function was created.

I don't have access to the reference of this RDS admin package, but it is most likely that the error is because of it.

```
begin
    rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object(
        p_obj_name     => 'DBA_OBJECTS',
        p_grantee      => 'MASTER_USER',
        p_privilege    => 'SELECT',
        p_grant_option => true);
end;
/
```

However, as you are grating `with admin option` then you must consider this

> To be able to grant privileges on an object, your account must have
> those privileges granted to it directly with the grant option, or via
> a role granted using with admin option. **In the most common case, you
> may want to grant SELECT on a DBA view that has been granted to the
> SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role. If that role isn't already directly granted
> to your user using with admin option, then you can't transfer the
> privilege.** If you have the DBA privilege, then you can grant the role
> directly to another user

Also take in consideration the deprecated versions in Amazon RDS for Oracle releases

[Amazon RDS Oracle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.PatchComposition.html)